# Simplifying coefficients of expressions with MATLAB's symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab, symbols, symbolic-math

Suppose I have the following MATLAB code.

```
syms a b c1 c2

c1 = a + b + pi*b
c2 = a + b + 0.5*b
```

Then c1 gets evaluated to `a + b + pi*b` and c2 to `a + (3*b)/2`

However, I need MATLAB to calculate double precision values for the coefficients for a and b and not just symbolic numbers.

How do I do this? e.g. I want c1 to be evaluated as `a + 4.1416*b` and c2 as `a+ 1.5*b`

Also suppose I am interested in doing arithmetic like c1*c2, c1*5, I would like the coefficients of a and b to evaluated as double-precision numbers and not abstract symbolic expressions like
fractions.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic expressions cannot contain exactly “double precision” numbers, but you can get floating-point numbers:

```
c1 = a + b + vpa(pi)*b
```

or

```
c2 = vpa(a + b + 0.5*b)
```

Some computations, like `solve` or `int`, will still switch to exact numbers internally, but your results should always have the floating-point form.

You can change the precision used in the computations using `digits`:

```
digits(16) % double doesn't have more either
```